# How to do Date comparisons in elastic search script?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm try to write a update script that will update the record only if the date of the updatedAt field is greater than the updatedAt date on the source record.

This is the script that I am using, don't mind the $ and {} they are string literal syntax in javascript.

The script uses painless.

```
`ctx.op = ${moment(updatedAt).unix()} > ctx._source["updatedAt"] ? "update" : "none";`
```

The mapping for the field is Date with no specified format. When I try to do this query I get this error:

```
{
  "took": 7,
  "errors": true,
  "items": [
    {
      "update": {
        "_index": "search",
        "_type": "locations",
        "_id": "119",
        "status": 400,
        "error": {
          "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason": "failed to execute script",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "script_exception",
            "reason": "runtime error",
            "caused_by": {
              "type": "class_cast_exception",
              "reason": "Cannot apply [>] operation to types [java.lang.Integer] and [java.lang.String]."
            },
            "script_stack": [
              "ctx.op = 1485985330 > ctx._source[\"updatedAt\"] ? \"update\" : \"none\";",
              "                                 ^---- HERE"
            ],
            "script": "ctx.op = 1485985330 > ctx._source[\"updatedAt\"] ? \"update\" : \"none\";",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: i did some date manipulations and comparison back then but using groovy not painless